# Traverse and return html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-parsing

Lets say I've this HTML code:

```
<div>
    <h2>You know, I am a Heading!</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>I am the first li</li>
        <li>I am the second li</li>
        <li>I am the third li</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button onclick="go()" style="width:100px">Go!</button>
```

On the press of "Go!" button, the JavaScript would be called that would return me the node elements of the DOM.

```
<script>     
function go() {
  var childNodes = document.body.childNodes;
  for(var i=0; i<childNodes.length; i++) {
    var domElement = childNodes[i];
            doSomethingWithTheReturnedTag(); 
  }
}
</script>
```

What exactly I'm trying to do is when the button is clicked, my script goes through the entire HTML document and get each tag and perform an operation on the returned tag.

Just need suggestions if at all this is possible or there is some better approach to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');`

Answer (score 0):

To loop over all DOM elements:

```
  <script>     
    function go() {
    var items = startElem.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = items.length; i--;) {
       //perform operation on elment
    }
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, however what it returns to me is the object value for the DOM elements. For example, for <ul>, it would return [object HTMLUListElement]. Can I convert it to proper <ul> tag?

Comment: Simply by using items[i].innerHTML, example in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vyUvX/

Comment: Thanks @radia for replying back quickly. I'll now try to implement it to my use-case.